# How to use two models in Tensorflow object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

In `tensorflow` Object Detection API we are using `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17` model to detect 90 general objects. I want to use this model for detection.
Next, I have trained `faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28` model to detect a custom object. I wish to use this in the same code where I will be able to detect those 90 objects as well as my new trained custom object. How to achieve this with single code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have achieved this by doing the following code in detect_object.py

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
from PIL import Image
import cv2

from utils import label_map_util
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

# ------------------ Knife Model Initialization ------------------------------ #
knife_label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap('training/labelmap.pbtxt')
knife_categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(
    knife_label_map, max_num_classes=1, use_display_name=True)
knife_category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(knife_categories)

knife_detection_graph = tf.Graph()

with knife_detection_graph.as_default():
    knife_od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.GFile('inference_graph_3/frozen_inference_graph.pb', 'rb') as fid:
        knife_serialized_graph = fid.read()
        knife_od_graph_def.ParseFromString(knife_serialized_graph)
        tf.import_graph_def(knife_od_graph_def, name='')

    knife_session = tf.Session(graph=knife_detection_graph)

knife_image_tensor = knife_detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
knife_detection_boxes = knife_detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name(
    'detection_boxes:0')
knife_detection_scores = knife_detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name(
    'detection_scores:0')
knife_detection_classes = knife_detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name(
    'detection_classes:0')
knife_num_detections = knife_detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name(
    'num_detections:0')
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

# ------------------ General Model Initialization ---------------------------- #
general_label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap('data/mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')
general_categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(
    general_label_map, max_num_classes=90, use_display_name=True)
general_category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(
    general_categories)

general_detection_graph = tf.Graph()

with general_detection_graph.as_default():
    general_od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.GFile('ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17/frozen_inference_graph.pb', 'rb') as fid:
        general_serialized_graph = fid.read()
        general_od_graph_def.ParseFromString(general_serialized_graph)
        tf.import_graph_def(general_od_graph_def, name='')

    general_session = tf.Session(graph=general_detection_graph)

general_image_tensor = general_detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name(
    'image_tensor:0')
general_detection_boxes = general_detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name(
    'detection_boxes:0')
general_detection_scores = general_detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name(
    'detection_scores:0')
general_detection_classes = general_detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name(
    'detection_classes:0')
general_num_detections = general_detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name(
    'num_detections:0')
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #


def knife(image_path):
    try:
        image = cv2.imread(image_path)
        image_expanded = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
        (boxes, scores, classes, num) = knife_session.run(
            [knife_detection_boxes, knife_detection_scores,
                knife_detection_classes, knife_num_detections],
            feed_dict={knife_image_tensor: image_expanded})

        classes = np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32)
        scores = np.squeeze(scores)
        boxes = np.squeeze(boxes)

        for c in range(0, len(classes)):
            class_name = knife_category_index[classes[c]]['name']
            if class_name == 'knife' and scores[c] > .80:
                confidence = scores[c] * 100
                break
            else:
                confidence = 0.00
    except:
        print("Error occurred in knife detection")
        confidence = 0.0   # Some error has occurred
    return confidence


def general(image_path):
    try:
        image = cv2.imread(image_path)
        image_expanded = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
        (boxes, scores, classes, num) = general_session.run(
            [general_detection_boxes, general_detection_scores,
                general_detection_classes, general_num_detections],
            feed_dict={general_image_tensor: image_expanded})

        classes = np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32)
        scores = np.squeeze(scores)
        boxes = np.squeeze(boxes)

        object_name = []
        object_score = []

        for c in range(0, len(classes)):
            class_name = general_category_index[classes[c]]['name']
            if scores[c] > .30:   # If confidence level is good enough
                object_name.append(class_name)
                object_score.append(str(scores[c] * 100)[:5])
    except:
        print("Error occurred in general detection")
        object_name = ['']
        object_score = ['']

    return object_name, object_score


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(' in main')
```

I can do

```
import detect_object
detect_object.knife("image.jpg")  # to detect whether knife is present in image(this is custom trained model)

detect_object.general("image.jpg")  # to detect those 90 objects from TF API
```

I know there is knife model in TF API but it is not that much accurate so I retrained it for only knife. Finally I have two models 
1. First model is to detect only knife,
2. Second model is to detect general object as usual

Comment: Can I combine two graphs of object detection models which are supposed to run back-to-back? Based on the result of the first model I need to dynamically crop the input and feed it to the second model, I want all of this in one graph

Comment: I tried this -> https://github.com/sachinkmohan/run_obj_det_sem_seg
and did not work :(
Also raised a bug with tensorflow -> https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/53834

Answer (score 2):

You cant combine both the models. Have two sections of code which will load one model at a time and identify whatever it can see in the image. 
Other option is to re-train a single model that can identify all objects you are interested in

Comment: Can I combine two graphs of object detection models which are supposed to run back-to-back? Based on the result of the first model I need to dynamically crop the input and feed it to the second model, I want all of this in one graph